# Motherboard keeps turning itself on after turned off with power switch

Tags: motherboard, power-management

I have a Gigabyte Z370 HD3P motherboard and it keeps turning itself on after being turned off with the power switch. I know the switch itself is fine because it only turns on the machine when asked, so it is not shorted out. Also, when the switch is pressed, the machine turns off correctly... but then comes back on about 2 seconds later. It is not a peripheral, I have unplugged every peripheral including the monitor and it has the same problem. There is no operating system and the drive is not formatted.

Here are the BIOS settings I have tried to no effect:

- Erp
- Rc6
- Wake on LAN
- AC BACK

In general, all the power related settings are disabled and I have tried Erp both enabled and disabled and the problem occurs under both settings.

Comment: I have had the same problem, the solution was to remove my Wireless Network card from the PCI slots. Does removing all PCI connected cards help? If it does, try the trial and error method to find out which one is at fault here.

Comment: @NordlysJeger There are no cards in any of the PCI slots.